# Helping a friend = Too many fines and not enough money

Tags: licensing, speeding, forgery, fines, alberta

A insured a motor bike for B, who signed it over to A. Since then, A has gotten close to $1000 in photo radar tickets.

After multiple attempts to stop B from speeding, A cancelled the insurance. After A received 2 more tickets, A took the license plate and told B that A needs the tickets paid.

B won't pay, so A said he would sell the bike to cover it. Now hypothetically it's not A's bike, but A is the registered owner of it. (Because B now has insurance from a different company, A assumes B forged A's signature.)

Can B do that?  What legal options does A have? A cannot afford the tickets and doesn't want any marks against him for whatever could happen license wise. (A only has a learners class 7 and is worried that it will affect his drivers class 5.)

Comment: Why haven't you reported this to police? Clearly your "friend" is happy to commit fraud and traffic violations at your expense.

Comment: I do not know of Alberta, but in most places the fines are paid by the infractor (the driver). Some are directly addressed to the vehicle owner when the driver identity cannot be determined (for example photo radar), but the vehicle owner can answer by identifying the driver. Since it is to be expected that your "friend" will try to avoid his responsabilities and deny your identification, talk to a lawyer about how to do this properly.

Comment: For example, in the U.K. you would get a letter, and the very first question is: Were you the driver? If you were not the driver, then who is the driver? So you’d answer truthfully who the driver is, and if they don’t pay it goes to court and the court will make them pay, more than the normal cost.

Comment: Possession is 9/10s of the law. Does have control over the bike and the ability to deny A access to it?

Comment: Possession of the title is enough.

Comment: Concerning the insurance: I drove and insured a car owned by someone else for several years. Completely legal. Insurance agent just told me that the car is only insured when driven with permission of the owner, so I couldn’t drive after falling out with the owner, and I couldn’t lend the car to a friend, because they wouldn’t have permission of the owner.

Answer (score 2):

The bike was signed over to A, which constitutes a sale. So A owns the bike. He can sell his bike as he sees fit.

Further, A should have responded to all tickets with identifying B as the driver.